# Convert xml format to Java

Tags: java, xml, converters, data-conversion

I need to convert datasource configuration in xml to java.
I am using DataSource impl of Java. Trying to use OracleDataSource object but there are features that I could not defined, for example : statement-cache-size

Do you have suggestions in which DataSource impl should I use? What is the correct use in order to transform the object?

XML:

```
<data-source action="update" name="serverNm">
          <database-name />
          <minimum-pool-size>0</minimum-pool-size>
          <maximum-pool-size>6</maximum-pool-size>
          <connection-timeout>1</connection-timeout>
          <idle-timeout>600</idle-timeout>
          <orphan-timeout>30</orphan-timeout>
          <statement-cache-size>100000</statement-cache-size>
          <other-props>stmtBuffCleanPolicy=;</other-props>
          <default-user />
          <default-password />
          <disable-auto-connectioncleanup>false</disable-auto-connectioncleanup>
          <description />
          <jndi-name>jdbc/serverNm</jndi-name>
          <logging-options>-1</logging-options>
          <config-properties>
                 <property name="URL"
                       value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostName:1521:S81U" />
                 <property name="user" value="user" />
                 <property name="password" value="password" />
                 <property name="driverType" value="" />
                 <property name="driverConfig" value="" />
                 <property name="connRateThrottle" value="60000" />
                 <property name="connectionProperties"
                 value="oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible=true;oracle.jdbc.TcpNoDelay=true;oracle.jdbc.RetainV9LongBindBehavior=true" />
          </config-properties>
   </data-source>
```

Java :

```
   OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
              ds.setDriverType(dbDriverClassName);
              ds.setURL(host);
              ds.setUser(user);
              ds.setPassword(password);
```

Thanks

Comment: Where does this data-source xml fragment come from?  I assume some server config?  There is no direct correlation between the two.  You are mixing apples with oranges.  If the xml is from a persistence.xml or similar, than many of those properties as for the app server's usage.

Comment: what are the attributes missing in OracledataSource implementation?

Comment: @Yohannes  for example : statement-cache-size,orphan-timeout,maximum-pool-size

Answer (score 0):

Look into interface [PoolDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12826/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSource.html) and some of its possible [implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm#CHDEHFHE) if that meets your need.